# Bash Passing variables to string

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, sh, zsh

So, I am trying to create an alias to open the browser in a specific URL for me when I run the `pr` command on my command line.

```
function pr() {
  repoName=(basename `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`)
  branchName=(`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`)
  $repoName <- printing a-public
  $branchName <- printing acq-248
  open -a "Google Chrome" "https://bitbucket.org/company/$repoName/pull-requests/new?source=$branchName&event_source=branch_list"
}
```

So, when I run `pr`, I can see the $repoName and the $branchName has the right value, but the opened url does interprets it partially -> `https://bitbucket.org/company/Users/v/projs/a-public/pull-requests/new?source=acq-248&event_source=branch_list`

So, what would be the right way of passing these variables to concatenate into the URL I wanna open ?

Comment: Why are you tagging this question as _zsh_  and _sh_ and _shell_, if you are interested in a bash solution only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

both of them are an array assignment.

```
repoName=(basename `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`)
branchName=(`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`)
```

If you want to expand the command output in a variable use command substitution without the backticks but the `$( )`

```
repoName=$(basename $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel))
branchName=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
```

Try quoting the url with the `%q` so it can be pass to the shell as a safe argument.

```
var="https://bitbucket.org/company/$repoName/pull-requests/new?source=$branchName&event_source=branch_list"
```

Quote it shell safe.

```
printf -v url '%q' "$var"
```

Now try your command.

```
open -a "Google Chrome" "$url"
```

Comment: You killed it man, tks. I didn't know about $() thing. working smoothly!

Comment: Glad to be of help.

Comment: You should quote the inner command substitution and use lowercase variable names. To make the variables local to the function, use the `declare` or `local` keyword: `declare repo=$(basename "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)")`

Comment: @Freddy, right declare the variables local but without the assignment.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but here it is. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#local_var.3D.24.28cmd.29

Comment: The variabale names are perfectly fine. the quoting of the inner `$()` should be done.

Comment: [Are there naming conventions for variables in shell scripts?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42847/are-there-naming-conventions-for-variables-in-shell-scripts)

Comment: Sure, It is now up to the OP what he wants to use for the variables. but the variable names is not all caps.